# is it possible to add video in android push notification?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-remoteview, android-push-notification

Is ti possible too embedded video into android rich notification as it possible in iOS? I know that the android officially still do not support that, but it may be some tricky way to improvise that? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most android developers have no idea how it is done in iOS. Where do you want to show that video?

Comment: just create a custom Notification layout and add an exo player there & listen for "notification receive" with a broadcast.receiver, which gets the video ID/URL pushed. "thanks in advance" does not motivate me to program that for you.

Comment: You have to send url as notification payload and build proper notification ui in application.

Comment: @3mpty can you provide me some example?

Comment: @DragisaDragisic hey is it done? I  need to do the same.

Comment: @SapnaSharma I didn't menage to make video in push notifications. :(

Comment: Not sure but it may be possible. I am [searching further about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65773220/2289835)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to show video on RemoteViews. You can use only widgets that are described in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

As you show in comments as [example](https://docs.swrve.com/user-documentation/push-notifications/creating-push-campaigns/about-rich-push-notifications/#Video), it's not a video in the notification, it's a simple image (but as I assume, when you click on it, some apps, that can show video by URL (or something like that), will be started and showing you content, that's all)

Comment: Not sure but it may be possible. I am [searching further about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65773220/2289835)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement FCM Messages 'Data message'. This will allow you to send custom json data. More info here: [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options). Such message will not be shown automatically - after receiving you need to build your custom notification layout. More info here: [Android dev documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) It's not possible to show video directly on notification panel. Checkout how youtube does it.

Comment: Not sure but it may be possible. I am [searching further about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65773220/2289835)